# How to exclude ash_approx_common from app-engine library in gae-endpoint gradle.build

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, google-cloud-endpoints

I have been having problems with my gradle build for the app engine endpoints in android studio.

Says that I have duplicate files during packaging of APK

Origin 1

```
    Origin 1: /home/c/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.appengine/appengine-api-1.0-sdk/1.9.19/188d623cac7193f2f46f44dc7b76f3ba2342a09f/appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.19.jar
```

Origin 2

```
    Origin 2: /home/c/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.appengine/appengine-endpoints/1.9.19/bf21fb26e6f26a9da29f3db35f183092741f3c02/appengine-endpoints-1.9.19.jar
```

Then it gives the option/solution to:

```
You can ignore those files in your build.gradle:
android {
  packagingOptions {
  }
    exclude 'com/google/appengine/repackaged/org/apache/commons/codec/language/bm/ash_approx_common.txt'
}
```

But I do not have android{} inside the endpoint build.gradle. And neither can I add it? how else can I exclude/solve this problem

My code:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.22'
}
}

repositories {
    jcenter();
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

dependencies {
    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.19'

    compile ('com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.19')
    compile ('com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.19')
    compile ('javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5')
    compile ('com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:5.1.1')
    compile ('com.ganyo:gcm-server:1.0.2')
    compile ('com.sendgrid:sendgrid-java:2.2.1'){
        exclude(group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient')
        exclude(group: 'org.json', module: 'json')
    }
}

appengine {
    downloadSdk = true
    appcfg {
        oauth2 = true
    }
    endpoints {
        getClientLibsOnBuild = true
        getDiscoveryDocsOnBuild = true
    }
}
```